# how to add google map api in magento2.1

Tags: magento2, google-map

i have google map api i just want get these longitude and latitude 
my phtml code is

```
<?php $address=$_GET['location'];//location=Manhattan


$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
$url="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=".$block->getApiKey();
```

it will genrate a link i.e https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Manhattan&key=AIzaSyBr3mn7y42_iHMTcE_5zEJk_uSGCFXIFGk

i just want this link data into my php variable to pass in longitude and latitude of my script function